# JQuery Overlay Opacity and Text Problem

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list show a bunch of logos as blocks. When the user hovers over any logo I'm using a div to create a semi-transparent overlay, but on top of the overlay I would like to put some text with a button.

Everything is working fine, but when I hover over the item the text tends to look like it's behind the overlay. If however I set the overlay opacity to 1 (opaque) the text shows up just fine. Either that or the text is adopting the opacity of the overlay.

Here's the HTML:

```
<li class="portfolioElement pfe28">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="portfolioMore">Click here for more information.</div>
    <div class="portfolioText">
            <h3 class="portfolioTitle">Company</h3>
        <p class="portfolioDescription">
        Description...
        </p>
        <p>Locations: Toronto - Canada, Brisbane - Australia</p>
        <p>Click here to see more</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

The div with the class set to portfolioMore is supposed to be displaying above the div overlay.

Is there any known problem with showing an opaque div over a semi-transparent div? Or is this a problem with my code somewhere?

Thanks
Jacques

And here is the CSS:

```
.portfolioMore
{
    background: black url(Portfolio.png) -194px -704px;
    //height:46px;
    //width:46px;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:-65px;
    position:inherit;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:9pt;
    color:white;
    opacity:1;
    -moz-opacity:1;

}
```

and the second CSS part:

```
.overlay
{
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS that goes along with this?  

There shouldn't be any problem with what you're trying to do.  One thing that might help is putting <div class="overlay"> after the <div class="portfolioMore"> in the markup.  Source order shouldn't matter here, but in some cases and browsers it does.

Comment: can you show the CSS rules of the overlay and portfolioMore elements?

Comment: Hey guys, I've added the two CSS rules to the original post. Thanks for the feedback. I'm about to try Pat's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly setting the stacking order of your div's by setting position: relative on both of them and giving a z-index:

```
.portfolioMore {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    /* other css declarations */
}

.overlay {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    /* other css declarations */
}
```

Comment: position: relative didn't seem to change anything, but position:absolute on the overlay rule fixed it. It seems I've gone for an overly complicated route here. In fact over all the years that I've been working with HTML CSS I've never gotten to fully understand Absolute vs Relative, now I see Fixed being used, but it apparently has bugs. Got any good resources to fully explain positioning in CSS?

Comment: Glad to hear you got it fixed and I do indeed: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: mother of all things green, what a an absolutely perfect tutorial. Pat, that's the best it's ever been explained to me. Thanks a bunch, really appreciate it.

Comment: Not a problem - once you get your head around CSS positioning/floating, CSS only layouts get a lot easier.